# Silverlight WCF netTcpBinding problem

Tags: wcf, silverlight-4.0, nettcpbinding, clientaccesspolicy.xml

Trying to call a WCF with a netTcpBinding via Silverlight, I am getting the error:

"TCP error code 10013: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.. This could be due to attempting to access a service in a cross-domain way while the service is not configured for cross-domain access. You may need to contact the owner of the service to expose a sockets cross-domain policy over HTTP and host the service in the allowed sockets port range 4502-4534."

My WCF service is hosted in IIS7, bound to:

http://localhost.myserivce.com on port 80
and net.tcp on port 4502

I can see http://localhost.myserivce.com/myservice.svc if I browse to it (my hosts file is pointing this domain to localhost).
I can also see http://localhost.myserivce.com/clientaccesspolicy.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<access-policy>
   <cross-domain-access>
      <policy>
         <allow-from http-request-headers="*">
            <domain uri="*" />
         </allow-from>
         <grant-to>
            <socket-resource port="4502-4534" protocol="tcp" />
         </grant-to>
      </policy>
   </cross-domain-access>
</access-policy>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try to establish a TCP connection in port range 4502-4534, Silverlight will first post a request on port 943 to retrieve the client access policy file content - It won't read the file at http://localhost.myserivce.com/clientaccesspolicy.xml, because this is only for HTTP requests.
You need to configure your server to listen on TCP port 943, expect a request string equal to `<policy-file-request/>` and reply with the xml file content.

The code below shows a basic implementation, you need to pass it a local IPEndPoint using port 943:

```
public class SocketPolicyServer
{
    private const string m_policyRequestString = "<policy-file-request/>";
    private string m_policyResponseString;
    private TcpListener m_listener;
    bool _started = false;

    public SocketPolicyServer()
    {
        m_policyResponseString = File.ReadAllText("path/to/clientaccesspolicy.xml");
    }

    public void Start(IPEndPoint endpoint)
    {
        m_listener = new TcpListener(endpoint);
        m_listener.Start();
        _started = true;
        m_listener.BeginAcceptTcpClient(HandleClient, null);
    }

    public event EventHandler ClientConnected;
    public event EventHandler ClientDisconnected;

    private void HandleClient(IAsyncResult res)
    {
        if(_started)
        {
            try
            {
                TcpClient client = m_listener.EndAcceptTcpClient(res);
                m_listener.BeginAcceptTcpClient(HandleClient, null);
                this.ProcessClient(client);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Trace.TraceError("SocketPolicyServer : {0}", ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        _started = false;
        m_listener.Stop();
    }

    public void ProcessClient(TcpClient client)
    {
        try
        {
            if(this.ClientConnected != null)
                this.ClientConnected(this, EventArgs.Empty);

            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(client.GetStream(), Encoding.UTF8);
            char[] buffer = new char[m_policyRequestString.Length];
            int read = reader.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

            if(read == buffer.Length)
            {
                string request = new string(buffer);

                if(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase.Compare(request, m_policyRequestString) == 0)
                {
                    StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(client.GetStream());
                    writer.Write(m_policyResponseString);
                    writer.Flush();
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Trace.TraceError("SocketPolicyServer : {0}", ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            client.GetStream().Close();
            client.Close();
            if(this.ClientDisconnected != null)
                this.ClientDisconnected(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This has changed as of SL4 RTM.  A SL4 net.tcp client will not look for the client access policy on tcp 943, but will instead use the old method of using the root of the webserver, port 80.  Oddly, this isn't really well documented anywhere, but I can confirm that this is the behavior as of the release.

Bottom line, as of SL4 RTM, the method you describe should work and the other answer here does not.